# learning rails, trying to build blog categorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on building a blog with categorization. I am a bit stuck on how to implement categorization in the form. I have setup a has many through relationship and want to add check boxes to associate a blog with multiple categories. What I have so far is passing the categories through to the view, and I can list them out, however I cannot get the form_for method working for some reason.

Here is my code.

blog model

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body, :title, :image
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :categories, through: :categorizations
  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }

  validates :title, :body, :presence => true

end
```

Category Model

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :blogs, through: :categorizations
  attr_accessible :name
end
```

Categorization Model

```
class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :blog_id, :category_id
  belongs_to :blog
  belongs_to :category
end
```

Blog new controller

```
 def new
    @blog = Blog.new
    @categories = Category.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @blog }
    end
  end
```

Blog new form view

```
<%= form_for(@blog, :url => blogs_path, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
  <% if @blog.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@blog.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this blog from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @blog.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :body %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    Categories:
    <% @categories.each do |category| %>
      <% fields_for "blog[cat_attributes][]", category do |cat_form| %>
        <p>
          <%= cat_form.check_box :name %>
        </p>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This code is my failing point

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
          <% fields_for "blog[cat_attributes][]", category do |cat_form| %>
            <p>
              <%= cat_form.check_box :name %>
            </p>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
```

Although I am not positive I am approaching any of it right since I am currently learning. Any advice on how to accomplish this.

Thanks,
CG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you probably don't need a separate `Categorization` model unless there's a use case you haven't described here. You can set up a many-to-many relationship like this:

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :blogs
end
```

You should have a database table like this:

```
class CreateBlogsCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :blogs_categories, id: false do |t|
      t.references :blog
      t.references :category
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can construct the view like this:

```
<div class="field">
  Categories:
  <% @categories.each do |category| %>
    <%= label_tag do %>
      <%= check_box_tag 'blog[category_ids][]', category.id, @blog.category_ids.include?(category.id) %>
      <%= category.name %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Lastly, in your `form_for`, you specify `url: blogs_path` - you should remove this if you plan to use this form for the `edit` action as well, because that should generate a PUT request to `/blogs/:id`. Assuming you used `resources :blogs` in routes.rb, Rails will determine the correct path for you based on the action used to render the form.

Comment: Thanks this seems to work. I was using the has many through technique as Rails cast says that has and belongs to many is the less popular way to do this sort of thing. However the form logic seems to work for both. Thank you for the help :)